# Applying a new background color to Jquery's slider handles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am not sure why I am having such troubles with this. I have browsed Jquery's slider css file and found the class name of the handles. `.ui-slider-handle` and it even says in the API docs that is the name of it [Slider API doc link](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/), but whenever I add `background` or `background-color` and give it a color, it does nothing. The same thing for trying to get the handles to cover the entire bar.

I created a demo page on a site I have to show what I am trying to do. [Demo page](http://optimumwebdesigns.com/scroll)

```
.ui-slider-handle {
  height: 100%;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Also if someone doesn't mind. I am trying to make the words "Budget" appear in the red part (the budgeted range), but when I applied this: `<div class="ui-slider-range">Budget</div>` into my html, the word Budget shows to the far left of the slider. The html is like this:

```
<div id="slider-range">
   <div class="ui-slider-range">Budget</div>
</div>

.ui-slider-range {
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

How can I add the `background-color` to the slider handles and add the word "budget", so that it is in the middle of the red area?

Comment: try to check with inspect element tool if your rules are "overwritten" by the ones dinamically created by the plugin

Comment: They would have to be if mine aren't showing up. I even added `!important`... `background-color: #000 !important;`

Answer (score 1):

To change ui-slide-handler color, try:

```
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {   
    background: yellow !important; 
}
```

This is the rule to be overwritten.

The original rule is the following:

```
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background: #e6e6e6 url("images/ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png") 50% 50% repeat-x;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #555555;
}
```

Comment: Awesome. This helped, but I can't seem to get the handles inside of the bar when I set to `height: 100%;`. Do you know about the budget word, in how to get that to actually sit the in the range area?

Comment: still working on it, but there seems to be problem related to z-index. To move the budget word you have to add to the div css the rule left:50% and then you have to find a way to bring it to the front

Comment: Doing that seems to automatically put the Budget word at the 50% mark naturally. I want it to be in the middle of the range no matter what range is selected.

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy to see all the rules that apply to any element in the page using browser dev tools element inspector.

Your rule isn't specific enough based on the existing rules that have higher specificity with selectors like:

```
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default
 /* and */
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-handle
```

A simple way to make more specific for one instance would be to use your ID of main widget in selector

```
#slider-range .ui-slider-handle
```

Or for more broad reaching use.... copy the most specific selector and use that. Last rule in page with same selector takes precedence

Comment: Thank you. Do you know about the word "Budget" that I mentioned in my question?

Comment: that would need to be in a different element. The plugin populates all the content that makes up the various slider parts in the empty target selector element

Comment: Do you mean just a different identifier like `<div id="budget-text">Budget</div>` If this is the case, then how could I get it to associate with where the `ui-slider-range` range is currently? OR do I nest the div within that?